# How set up secondary VPN connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, failover, vpc

How can I set up a secondary VPN connection like in  [this|http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html#VPNConnections] diagram?

If I set up a Customer Gateway to my secondary (public) IP and VPN connection to this secondary customer gateway (static - no BGP available) I obtain two more tunnels, in diagram (linked above) the tunnels are the same of primary VPN connection (crossed in customer configuration).

I don't found any reference in doc.

Thanks.

Comment: You want a secondary VPN connection to different equipment at the same data center for the same routes?

Comment: Yes, that’s right